# how to find substring between given characters in smarty?

Tags: smarty

I have following code in php to which I am looking in smarty

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = '[1]wholesale';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "[", "]");
$filename = substr(strrchr($fullstring, "]"), 1);

echo $parsed.'/'.$filename;
//Output 1/Wholesale
```

I want this output `1/Wholesale`in two different variables (as done in php `$parsed,$filename`) in `Smarty` (Let say string is `[1]wholesale`).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it this way:

```
{assign var="var" value="[1]wholesale"}

{$var|substr:($var|strpos:'['+1):($var|strpos:']' - $var|strpos:'['-1)}/{$var|substr:($var|strpos:']'+1)}
```

Output for this will be:

```
1/wholesale
```

However as you see it's rather quite illegible. You could of course move it to some function/modifier but as always I need to tell, the best option is to prepare data in PHP and then simply display it in Smarty not using advanced transformations.